# Understanding the phrase "Que Me Baile"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, letras-de-canciones

I'm still on this forever journey of improving my Spanish and I recently came across the song "Que Me Baile" by ChocQuibTown and Becky G. I was just wondering if anyone here knows why they use "Yo quiero que me baile" as opposed to "Yo quiero que él baile conmigo". Am I crazy? Are these sentences saying the same thing or are they completely different? I thought it would help if I reviewed over DOP and IOP but I confused myself even more (probably because I'm overthinking it!).

¡Hola! Siempre quiero mejorar mi español y recientemente encontré la canción "Que me Baile" de ChocQuibTown y Becky G. Me preguntaba si alguien aquí sabe por qué ellos usan "Yo quiero que me baile" en lugar de "Yo quiero que él baile conmigo". ¿Estoy loca? ¿Estas oraciones dicen lo mismo o son completamente diferentes? ¡¡Estoy confundida!! 
(Apologies if I made any mistakes in translating what I said!)

Answer (score 5):

Supposing the subject of "baile" is a third person (*he, she*), that "me" is an indirect object and introduces the beneficiary, being equivalent to "para mí."

- Quiero que **me** baile.
- Quiero que (él, ella) baile **para mí**. (I want him/her to dance **for me**.)

In a completely different context, that sentence could be used to mean that the person wants something he/she wears to fall loosely (not to fit tightly) on him/her:

- Quiero que la camisa me baile. (I want the shirt to fall loosely on me.)

In this case, the indirect object "me" is a "dativo simpatético", as it refers to something the person owns or wears.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the verb *bailar* is used as an euphemism or slang for having sex, (if you read the context in the song, you could read sentences as *Ella quiere (...) que le lea el cuerpo en Braile* and you could translate as *She wanna be read (...) her body in Braile System* or another sentence *Esta noche es de entierro, cero palabreo* is about *this night we are going to have sex without talk* also in slang). Mostly, the song manage slang, some of the Pacific coast from Colombia, so for that reason some words and sentences are difficult to understand even for people who have spanish as first language (believe me, i have to read the lyrics to give you a response). But mainly about your question the use of the sentence *que me baile* and not *que baile conmigo* (with the same meaning) is to keep the rhyme in the song.